# target not found: kxmlgui5

Tags: linux, upgrade

Whenever I try to update my packages, the error message appears which reads: Error:
Failed to process the transaction
target not found: kxmlgui5

How can I fix that...?
Please help me.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to upgrade?

Comment: Which distro you are trying to update ?

Comment: What's the exact command you're using? (Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/759621/edit) to answer these comments. We can then delete them and you have a more detailed question.)